# Integral convergence implies convergence in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f_n,f \in L^1(X,{\cal M},\mu)$ and $f_n \to f$ a.e., Show that if $\int f_n \to \int f$, then $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$

My trial is to use Fatou's Lemma, set $g_n = |f_n| + |f| - |f_n - f| \in L^{+}(X)$, then apply Fatou's Lemma, we have
$\liminf \int|f_n| + \liminf \int |f| - \limsup \int |f_n - f| \ge 2\int |f|$

It is obvious that $\liminf \int |f| = \int|f|$, so if we can show that $\liminf \int |f_n| = \int|f|$, we can finish this prove, but how to show this? Does $\int f_n \to \int f$ implies $\int |f_n| \to \int |f| ?$

Thanks!

Comment: Some condition is missing. As written, for $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, $f = 0$ and $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1)} - \chi_{[n+1,n+2)}$ satisfy the conditions but not the conclusion.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks! Can you explain why $f_n \to f$ a.e.?

Comment: For every $x\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $n > x \implies f_n(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: I think that the last assumption in your statement should be $\int|f_n| \to \int |f|$.

Comment: @Rigel Yeah I think so but this is one of my assignment questions, so I have to ask the professor next monday :(

Comment: Tell your professor you had difficulty with the original problem, and you got some help to see that it is actually false. If you solve it with the assumption $\int|f_n| \to \int |f|,$ the prof should be happy (especially since the prof assigned a bad problem)